# Adding Datasource object as property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, sqldatasource, web-controls

I have two problems:

I am creating a WebControl and I like to add `SqlDataSource` as its property. It doesn't matter under what is the property name, Visual Studio shows its name as Database. Following is my code and Visual Studio 2010 express shows all Data1~Data3 properties in Property Editor as "Database"

Second problem is when I click on arrow beside the Databse name in Property Editor I get an exception "The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"

Which part I'm doing wrong?

**My component code:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;

namespace Comp1 {
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:M1GridData runat=server></{0}:M1GridData>")]
    public class M1GridData : WebControl {

        public SqlDataSource Data1 { get; set; }
        public SqlDataSource Data2 { get; set; }
        public SqlDataSource Data3 { get; set; }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
                writer.Write("Something");
        }
    }
}
```

**My page code:**

```
<cc1:M1GridData ID="M1GridData1" runat="server" />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it works fine. may be you need to restart your visual studio or reinstall the component.

also check `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder in each of frameworks you installed in `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\` and delete its content. sometimes `ASP.NET` forgets to delete a cached dll and you get lots of non-sence errors because of that.